# How to align the texts in a layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I want to display some text in a ListView row with the following alignment:

```
Mike      10pt $1,233,500
Mike2    200pt $1,2,500
Holly     10pt $4500
```

But when I tried, I got this instead:

```
   Mike        10pt   $1,233,500
    Mike2    200pt       $12,500
    Holly            10pt  $4500
```

My layout file is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dl005_textfield_selected"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Mike"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#888888" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="10pt"
            android:textColor="#3498db" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myid"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$1,233,500"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#3498db" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)? It seems like it would be perfect for this layout. From the docs: "A layout that arranges its children into rows and columns." You can set cell text alignment to left/right as necessary.

Comment: Use of `TableLayout` is a recommended way and for your linearlayout when you'r using weight property with horizontal layout then its `width` must be `0dp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using a `TableLayout` instead which positions its children views into rows and columns. Also note that you need to remove `android:gravity="right"` from the third `TexView` because you need its contents left aligned.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/dl005_textfield_selected"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Mike"
            android:textColor="#888888" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="10pt"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#3498db" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myid"
            android:text="$1,233,500"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#3498db" />

    </TableRow>

    ...

</TableLayout>
```

You also need to remove the `layout_width` attributes on child `TextViews` as they are always set to `MATCH_PARENT`. You set the individual columns as *strechable* or *shrinkable* instead.

Comment: Since, I already made a listview for my app is it possible to do something like the table layout ?

Comment: Imitating the table layout wouldn't be wise in the long run. There are so many Android devices with every permutation/combination of screen size and pixel density, you'll keep fixing the layout for some while breaking it for others.